# Начало изучения PHP

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток, я начинающий, так сказать программист, хорошо знаю HTML и конечно же CSS... понятно дело, что на этом никуда не уедешь, начал изучать PHP, изучаю его по видео урокам "СПЕЦИАЛИСТ", закончил только 1 уровень из 4-х, но вот какая проблема, в этом уровне рассказывается о переменных, константах, условиях, циклах и функциях, как "родных" так и пользовательских... проблема в том, что я вроде знаю синтаксис того или иного действия, но когда доходит до практики и надо написать допустим калькулятор, у меня возникает проблема в последовательности приемах, и я не могу сообразить, что делать, хотя когда смотрю на готовый код, то мне все становиться понятно и уже после этого я могу написать его... подскажите, я тупой? сомневаюсь в этом... дальше уровни по видеоурокам я не трогаю, там во втором идет речь о Куках, Сессиях, MySQLе, но я не тороплюсь пока что переходить на сл уровень, хочу разобраться с первым... ведь все что есть в первом этого вполне достаточно для того чтобы написать допустим постраничную навигация, я знаю, но я не понимаю с чего начать и как это делать "( помогите кто чем может, может есть какой-то справочник, может из вас кто-то даст несколько уроков, может кто-то скажет кто что начинал писать или кто то просто даст задание... буду рад вашей помощи, спасибо и помогите

Comment: Есть такая пословица: "Чтобы стать хорошим писателем, нужно быть хорошим читателем", мораль в том, что нужно читать чужой код - это реально помогает. Ну и еще, чтобы стать программистом нужно программировать (с) А вообще, задали бы вы более конкретизированный вопрос :)

Comment: Каждый начинал с азов, думаю, что каждый может понять о что  я имел ввиду) спасибо за мораль:)

Answer (score 2):

Есть один хороший прием, как начать практиковаться в программировании: начните править чужой код. То есть, возьмите пару примеров и, изменяя код, смотрите, что меняется в работе программы. Как начнете скучать, читайте теорию и документацию. =)

Comment: спасибо, думаю Вы правы, обязательно по практикуюсь=) можете еще подсказать где взять мануал на русском языке?

Comment: @ling отлично! +1 написал прям из души крик :)

Comment: Хм. Ну, я пользуюсь [http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/][1], только на английском.

[1]:http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/

Comment: Когда не было русской документации и познаний в английском, правил чужие коды)

Answer (score 0):

Мое сугубо личное мнение: что только учится по видеокурсам специалиста очень энергозатратно, данных дается очень много, а то как вы будете практиковаться будет зависеть только от вашей силы воли. И скорее вы будете мчаться вперед без закрепления предыдущего материала.

Занимаясь на курсах по линуксу я вынужден был выполнять практику, контроль которой проводил преподаватель. Там было много инфы, которую я ТОГДА считал ненужной и неинтересной, и в самообучении я бы такие моменты явно бы пропускал, но очень многое мне пригодилось из-то, что я счел неактуальным.

Все это о том, что как ни крути а качество самообучения, где учащийся и преподаватель(как аудитор) одно лицо, заметно ниже чем традиционное, поэтому я считаю надо использовать несколько иной подход, чем систематический.

Сначала использовать литературу(но не видеокурсы) для быстрого вхождения в тему, которая поверхностно осветит возможности языка, но более менее детально опишет синтаксис основных конструкций. Далее черпать сведения из основной документации представленной к примеру для php на [php.net](http://php.net) использовать его в качестве основного справочника и привыкать к английскому языку. Дойдя до осознания, что свой код слишком уж "быдлокоден" можно углубляться в литературу(или качественные видеокурсы) высокого качества с детальным описанием тонкостей языка и их возможностей.

**П.С.**
Систематический подход без аудитора в целом очень тяжел и хотя данный метод я предпочел как очень правильный(что не значит удобный) для себя, не исключаю, что некоторые люди предпочитают систематический подход. потому что не хотят ломать привычную школьную систему мышления.

**П.П.С.** 
Быстрый старт в php, а был он очень быстрым произошел так как описывает [@ling](/users/1252/ling). Единственное, что я стартовал с полного нуля и чужой сырец являл собой истинный эталон быдлокода.

**П.П.П.С** Мне кажется, что подобным вопросам надо обязательно ставить тег обучение, так подобных тем открывалось немало - полезно бы было отправлять новичков собирать информацию по ключевому слову.

Answer (score 0):

Я присоединяюсь к просьбе Sleepika, так как тоже начинающий в этом деле) пусть опытные учат не опытных :D

Comment: Ты бы еще добавил "во веки веклов -аминь!")) Здесь опытные, итак, учат неопытных. Но так как деньги им не платят, они очень злые и требовательные, подавай им сложные, интересные вопросы с ясной формулировкой и без всяких просьб написать "напишите за меня фэйсбук"(хотя это требование предъявляют все нормальные преподаватели).

Comment: зачем писать FaceBook если он уже есть? у меня в планах совсем другое, и если вот вы, опытные программисты на php наберетесь не много терпения и с уважением отнесетесь к нам, каким-то несчастным новичкам, то у нас все не принеприменно получиться, и когда мы уже с легкостью будем "писать код", то обязательно вспомним, что были люди, которые делились опытом и умением, и поверьте, будем вспоминать вас всех только хорошим словом и по своему конечно будем вам благодарны... во веки веко-аминь !))